# Difficulties with LSF resource usage arguments -

Tags: lsf

What's the magic in getting the usage strings to work, we always get the message below:

```
bsub -n 8 -R "rusage[mem=20000]" hostname
```

> Resource requirement string is invalid. Job not submitted.

We are using the free community edition - some uncertainty about if this could be the problem.  This is not mentioned as a characteristic of the community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried my CE cluster. Works fine.  Have you changed any options in lsf.conf?  Or, are there any esub's installed that could be changing the submission options?

```
$ lsid
IBM Spectrum LSF Community Edition 10.1.0.0, Jun 15 2016
Copyright IBM Corp. 1992, 2016. All rights reserved.
US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
```

```
$ bsub -n 8 -R "rusage[mem=20000]" hostname
Job <101> is submitted to default queue <normal>.
```

Comment: No - lsf.conf is untouched.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that upgrading to 10.2 (?) fixed this.  Very strange.